# Unable to copy array in PIC24FJ256GB206 with C30 compiler

Tags: c, arrays, memory, out-of-memory, mplab

I am trying to copy an array into another in `PIC24` `PIC24FJ256GB206` `microcontroller` with `C30 compiler`. Length of my array is more than `1500 bytes.`
Here is my code:-

```
int i=0;
int count = sizeof(rx.data.buff.fields.data);
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    rec.data.data_block.data[i] = rx.data.buff.fields.data[i];
}
```

But when I compile my code, I get this error:-

```
build/SINGLE_PORT_BAUD57600/production/_ext/733800733/rdso_icd_0065.o(.text+0x1604)c:\program files (x86)\microchip\mplab c30\bin\bin\..\bin/pic30-elf-ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found address size '3', this reader can only handle address sizes '2', '4' and '8'.
: In function `.LM403':
: undefined reference to `_rec'
make[2]: *** [dist/SINGLE_PORT_BAUD57600/production/StandaloneHCD.X.production.hex] Error 255
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Clearly it's not a logic issue. But what can be the reason for this?and What is the solution? thanks

Comment: The important part of the error message is "undefined reference to '_rec'". That means you have a declaration of `rec`, but the *definition*, where `rec` is actually defined, is missing. Is it defined in another source file that you should build with? Are you missing linking with a library or an object file?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)?

Comment: got my issue. I had linking problems

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 8 KB of data, you had to switch the Data model to Large:

```
ProjectProperties / Conf: / Memory model / Data model = Large
```